# How to resolve Azure “Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server”?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

right now I am working on a project with .Net CORE c# and entity framework database and I get an error

> SqlException: Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL
>   Server.

I followed a tutorial and I think I did everything fine...
The only difference is that I have my database hosted on Azure, it should matters?

Here is my connection string

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=firstdb123.database.windows.net;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
```

Here is a picture with my database

[image]

I have my EmployeesController and my EmployeeContext made by visual studio so it should be right.. but I don't know why it dose not work

Any help would be awesome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See that `Trusted_Connection=True;` bit in your your connection string?  That's a Windows shortcut that allows you to bypass the normal username/password credentials on a server.

You need to create secure Azure login, then use that to specify the connection string.

[This page](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) shows how a connection string is created in the various different SQL version.

Comment: And how do i do that? I am new into c# programming

Comment: When you created the Azure database, did you create a new username/password?  You will be able to create database users that are only able to do certain things (like a read only account), which makes it more secure in the future.

Comment: yes, i created an admin account, i have the id and pass but i dont know how to use them to login via C#

Answer (score 4):

You can connect to the Azure SQL using the `Active Directory Integrated` [authentication as it is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication).

Connection string should be like

```
connectionString="Server=servername.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Authentication='Active Directory Integrated'"
```

Comment: I'd like to add that Azure VMs aren't connected to Azure AD without some additional steps, and that this may not be smart to do and probably requires approval from your IT Admin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-windows-vm#create-a-windows-server-virtual-machine

Answer (score 3):

**Windows Logins of SQL Server:**

When a user connects through a Windows user account, SQL Server validates the account name and password using the Windows principal token in the operating system. AS your SQL Database is hosted in azure, we must ensure that your SQL Database and your .Net Core Application are in same Domain when use Windows Logins to connect to SQL Server.

More information about Windows Authentication, we can refer to: [Connecting Through Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-2017#connecting-through-windows-authentication)

**To Solve your problem, we can use SQL Server Authentication by pass the user name and password.**

We can set the User Name and Password at portal as below:

[image]

And we can get connection String at portal as below:

[image]

Then we can use this connection string in Entity Framework or ADO.NET code.

Answer (score 2):

It does matter that the database is hosted on Azure, because Azure doesn't have access to your windows account and can't verify that you are logged in with a windows account.

You could use the Server admin, but that is not very secure when you are going to run things in production.

> Members of the sysadmin fixed server role can perform any activity in the server.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017

To solve this you could create a database user by using:

```
CREATE USER [{username}] WITH PASSWORD=N'{password}'
```

Execute this on the database you need access to.
After creating the user you have to give it some permissions:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', [{username}];
```

'db_datareader' gives the user read-only permissions on the database. Maybe this is not enough for your user, then you van give it some more permissions by executing the statement again with another database role. More about the database roles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017

For Azure SQL databases it is not possible to do this via SQL Server Management Studio. More information about this:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins
- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5242/adding-users-to-azure-sql-databases/

Use this user in your connection string:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=firstdb123.database.windows.net;Database=TestDB;User Id={username};Password={password};MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Azure can get access to the Active directory account however [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/integrated-windows-authentication-with-an-azure-ad-identity/) must be adjusted with `Authentication=Active Directory Integrated`

Comment: Active Directory Domain Trusts are now supported. However, attempting to authenticate via the trusted domain still gives this error message. One would expect that with a domain trust that Windows authentication should work, but it doesn't. This kind of defeats the purpose of the domain trust.